# Is being referred to as a "Process Ninja" a negative thing?

Tags: feedback

I'm a Software Engineering lead (manager) and I find that developing systems in a large cross-discipline team works better when everyone follows the set processes. Ofcourse this works in theory, in real life not everyone will follow set processes and most of the time things still work, but most of the time when something goes wrong it's because someone ignored a process.

When performing a "post-mortem" or restrospective meeting on such cases the action points usually end up in two ways: either change a specific process or ensure that people follow the process.

I've once received feedback that I'm a "Process Ninja". I'm not really sure if this is positive or negative feedback. Does it mean that I'm too rigid?

Comment: I have never heard "ninja" used in a negative context.

Comment: The only person who knows is the person who gave you the feedback - why not ask them?

Comment: I voted to close as opinion based. While there is a valid answer saying "normally it's positive" it really does not help you understanding the specific case. In your *specific* case of a *specific* person saying this, your guess is as good as ours. Ask them.

Comment: the usual phrase is "code ninja".  meaning you're a sloppy but gifted programmer, a cowboy coder.  "process ninja" is *usually* used to mean the opposite of that, "all you do is you're good at organizing stuff".  *however* it could also be used completely positively, ie just pointing out that (not only) are you a great coder, but you're also good at boring crap like CI and meetings.  so it's *normally* used in contrast to "code ninja" *but* it could be a completely straiught complement.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser It is sometimes used as a social cathegory for "No Income No Jobs no Assets", but certainly that is not the sense it is been used here.

Comment: "Does it mean that I'm too rigid?" No, it's a compliment. Perhaps, it could have been used as a euphemism to refer to a deeper flaw that you have, but I think you're just overthinking this. I'm 95% sure that it was meant to be a compliment.

Answer (score 6):

In tech, Ninja is usually a term of appreciation.
The Ninja in pop culture are high skilled specialists who get their job done.
Since Ninjas are also adaptable, I doubt anybody would use it to signify something is to rigid.

The only way I see this could be negative, if it is used ironically.
As mentioned in the comments, the only person who knows for sure is the one who said it.
The meaning of spoken words depends on intention, it's impossible for us to know the intention of the speaker.
If you are unsure, you could ask.